# Is it possible to sendkeys / Post Message directly to a HtmlElement rather than to a webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, browser, sendkeys, postmessage

I would like to send keys to a c# web browser control element directly, not just the window with the correct focus.

Right now I am able to send a key using PostMessage and documentHandle and focus like this

i.e. Pseudo Code

```
HtmlElement el = getelement();
el.Focus();
IntPtr docptr = browser.Handle;
PostMessage(docptr,WM_KEYDOWN,1,0);
.... KEYCHAR, KEYUP..
```

I was wondering if anyone knows of any way to be able to do this in a background, so that the focus is not on the element. Basically is there a way to get a IntPtr to the HtmlElement itself, than use that instead in the PostMessage or SendKeys API rather than the browser handle/ptr.

Comment: Instead of describing your solution and how to make it work, describe the problem you're trying to solve instead. In the mean time, see http://seleniumhq.org/ if you need a basic web application tester.

Comment: The problem that I'm trying to solve is what I am asking.

I would like to sendkeys to an HTMLElement directly without having to reference it by a window and setting focus on it. aka How or is there a way to get a IntPtr to a HtmlElement.

I realize there are many test frameworks out there, and many which I have worked with before like selenium that could do something like this, however I'm looking for a Win32/C# solution.

Comment: HTML Elements don't have their own windows (except `<select>` in IE6), so they will not have separate handles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Those are windowless controls, mouse/keyboard messages are handled by their parent window, and the parent only relay message for the active control.

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way to go.

You can use the `HtmlElement` API to manipulate the element directly.

For precise instructions, please tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is for a specific application of emulating key strokes, to for example trigger javascript code for testing.
 
I realize you can .InvokeMemeber("click"), or .SetAttribute("value", value). But this is not what I'm talking about here.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at things like WaitN and Selenium.

IE also has a good programming interface to control the browser.

But there are downsides...

I'm currently working on a program that uses image recognition and control of the mouse/keys to control a browser as I can only really do what I want with the visual representation.

However that will dominate the computer and need full control.   Unless you run it in a virtual machine.

Comment: The question above is about the IE Interface. 

I'm looking for a .NET/C#/WIN32 solution to sending keys to a HtmlElement; specifically avoiding setting focusing on the control and sending the message to the whole window. I'm asking if anyone has sendkeys directly to the control instead.

Comment: if you can find out the control for the element you want you can send a message to it and set the text directly rather than send keys to it

Answer (score 0):

It took me a long time to find this, but you have to p/invoke GetWindow with the child command to repeatedly get child window handles until you get down to one that responds to GetClassName with "Internet Explorer_Server" or something like that.

Then PostMessage on that hWnd and the activeElement of the WebBrowser will recieve them.  Make sure you have the WM_KEYUP in there as that seems to be the important one.

Comment: your response would be more helpful with a code fragment, and a more definite statement about the class name, or something like that.